# How do I write 'findall' in a Prolog code itself?

Tags: prolog, prolog-findall

So, I am very new to Prolog and I have to write a short code about timetable.
How can I add the findall function to a code itself?

```
happening(monday,chemistry).
happening(monday,english).
happening(tuesday,chemistry).
happening(wednesday,maths).
happening(friday,chemistry).
happening(friday,maths).
```

And now I want to write a command that shows how many times do I have chemistry in a week.

```
find_lessons(X) :-
findall(X,happening(X,chemistry), Bag).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want the result, so the `Bag`, so you should rewrite `find_lessons(X)` to `find_lessons(Bag)`:

```
find_lessons(Bag) :-
    findall(X, happening(X,chemistry), Bag).
```

This will then give a *list* of days when there is a chemistry lesson, so:

```
?- find_lessons(Bag).
Bag = [monday, tuesday, friday].
```

to count the number of lessons, you can use `length/2`:

```
?- find_lessons(Bag), length(Bag, N).
Bag = [monday, tuesday, friday],
N = 3.
```

But one can do this more efficient. Right now there is overhead in constructing the list, and counting the elements. We can make use of the [**`aggregate`** library [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) and use the [**`aggregate/3`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=aggregate/3):

```
?- aggregate(count, X^happening(X, chemistry), Total).
Total = 3.
```

so we can count the number of chemistry lessons with:

```
:- use_module(library(aggregate))

num_chem_lessons(N) :-
    aggregate(count, X^happening(X, chemistry), N).
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast and correct answer!!